# Do I need to create a test version of my factory for unit testing?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, dependency-injection, factory

I create ship objects with my ShipFactory, but my ships have a dependency on my Accelerometer class (just a wrapper for the Android accelerometer). So I have my factory, when it's building a ship, pass in an accelerometer to the ships constructor.

This is my ShipFactory:

```
public class ShipFactory {
    private int screenX;
    private int screenY;
    private Context context;

    private Bitmap bitmap;

    // How can I mock this from in my factory?
    private Accelerometer accel;

    private Ship ship;

    public ShipFactory(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        accel = new Accelerometer(context);
    }

    public Ship makeShip(String shipType){
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.myship)
        ship = new Ship(context,screenX,screenY,bitmap,accel);
        return ship;
    }
}
```

So I make a ship like this:

```
   ShipFactory shipFactory = new ShipFactory(context);
   ship = shipFactory.makeShip("enemy");
```

But now let's say I want to unit my ship class and I want to mock out these dependencies. Context is easy to mock because I can just pass a mock context to my factory, but my factory still depends on accelerometer.

For unit testing this should I be creating a new factory just for testing? Or is it a benefit of using a factory that in my unit test I could forgo the factory all together and directly create a new ship by passing my mocks to in the ships constructor?

Comment: For clarification: do you want to unit test `Ship` or `ShipFactory`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ShipFactory` depends on `Ship`. However `Ship` does not depend on `ShipFactory`. Test your `Ship` independently of the `ShipFactory`. Since there's no dependency, there is no need for dependency injection.

Now later on when your factory gets bigger, you should write tests specifically for your factory. To accomplish that, I would suggest extracting all of the dependencies and **injecting** them in the constructor. You can overload the constructor to help you with this:

```
// you can use this for convenience
public ShipFactory(Context context){
    this(new BitmapProvider(context), new Accelerometer(context));
}

// use this for testing because you can provide mock versions
public ShipFactory(BitmapProvider provider, Accelerometer accel){
    this.provider = provider;
    this.accel = accel;
}

// wrapping BitmapFactory because it is a buncha static methods... aka a pain to mock
class BitmapProvider {
    Context context;
    public BitmapProvider(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap(int resId){
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes i wasn't even thinking about overloading. This was an important concept I was missing. Would a DI framework like spring make this easier?

Comment: you wouldn't need to overload with a framework but you would still need to extract the dependencies

Answer (score 2):

From your code, your `Ship` class exposes a public constructor so you don't need a `ShipFactory` to create a `Ship` object. Use the public `Ship` constructor instead and mock out the dependencies.

Comment: "your Ship class exposes a public constructor" you don't know that. It may be package-private

Comment: @TimCastelijns good point :) But from _Or is it a benefit of using a factory that in my unit test I could forgo the factory all together and directly create a new ship by passing my mocks to in the ships constructor._ I think I am right

Comment: So my class is small now and the factory isn't doing much but it will eventually have some logic in it to return a different ship based on the shipType (guess that wasn't clear). I still need a factory. My question was more about trying to wrap my head around DI and unit testing here

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the explicit Accelerometer dependency from ShipFactory and pass it in as you do with the Context object.

1) Create an AccelerometerFactory which accepts the Context in it's constructor, to generate an Accelerometer

2) Modify your ShipFactory constructor to accept the Context and an Accelerometer, or you could modify the makeShip method to accept the Accelerometer.

Now you can mock both the Context and the Accelerometer separately and pass them to your ShipFactory.

```
public class AccelerometerFactory {    
    private Context context;         

    public AccelerometerFactory(Context context){
        this.context = context;        
    }

    public Accelerometer makeAccelerometer(){        
        return new Accelerometer(context);
    }
}

public class ShipFactory {
    private int screenX;
    private int screenY;
    private Context context;

    private Bitmap bitmap;

    private Accelerometer accel;

    private Ship ship;

    public ShipFactory(Context context, Accelerometer accelerometer){
        this.context = context;        
        this.accel = accelerometer;
    }

    public Ship makeShip(String shipType){
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.myship)
        ship = new Ship(context,screenX,screenY,bitmap,accel);
        return ship;
    }
}

{// Calling code
    AccelerometerFactory accelFactory = new AccelerometerFactory(context);
    Accelerometer accel = accelFactory.makeAccelerometer(); // Note: Accelerometer class would have to be accessible here, not sure if this is the case for you
    ShipFactory shipFactory = new ShipFactory(context, accel);
    ship = shipFactory.makeShip("enemy");
}
```

Comment: Please try to write the minimum of code to solve the issue.